# Kafka Connect + Zookepeer not connecting

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka connect plugin that is deployed in a kafka cluster (in a stand alone mode, just for testing, the idea is to do it distributed). This kafka connect pluging connects to cluster's zookeper using curator and pulls some information from it to decide what to do with the messages.

The code is this:

```
protected CuratorFramework getCurator(final String zkConnection) {
    final CuratorFramework curator = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zkConnection,
            new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3));
    curator.start();
    return curator;
}

treeCache = new TreeCache(curator, settings.getConfigurationRoot());
...
treeCache.start()
```

It times out in that treeCache start, the configuration root path exists in local zookeeper (confirmed doing an ls  in the zookeeper-shell, and for the zkConnection string I've tried with:

- localhost:2181 (zookeeper is running in that port)
- localhost:2181, localhost:2182, localhost:2183
- :2181
- :2181,:2182,:2183
- 127.0.0.1:2181
  ... and so on

A kafka stream module running in a cloud connects with that zookeeper using the same piece of code... Any idea what is happening here?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error found! I was calling that getCurator in a try-with-resources statement and that was making the curator to get closed before starting the treeCache, once i move the curator out the try-with-resources statement and closed it in the stop method of the SinkTask, everything worked fine.

Cheers!